# Как настроить мониторинг Grafana для двухпроцессорной платы

Tags: zabbix, telegraf, grafana

Ранее выводил аллерты CPU для обычных однопроцессорных платформ, и тут вдруг понадобилось вывести общую загрузку двух CPU на двухпроцессорной материнке; поковырялся в конфиге, но кроме перебора параметров в функции [[inputs.cpu]] (https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/inputs/cpu/README.md), которую я добавил вручную вместо [[inputs.win_perf_counters]], не нашёл ничего дельного; подскажите, куда копать

Comment: Очень специфичная вещь. Лучше открыть issue на гитхабе и спросить об этом там

Comment: Благодарю, пойду искать